# Train spamassassin with POP3 or copied emails

Tags: pop3, spamassassin

I am still new at this so be gentle.

I have setup a server with postfix, dovecot, apachce2, PHP5, PHPmyadmin, spamassassin, clamav, amavis.

Now to train spamassassin apperently I need to use IMAP.

- But can I use POP3 saved emails in any way?
- Is it possible to copy mails from Thunderbird to the server and train spamassassin

Its because my spam folder on my thundird email client has alot of "good" examples of spam.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thunderbird stores its mail folders as mbox files (see the [Thunderbird FAQ](http://www.mozilla.org/support/thunderbird/faq#export)). If you locate the file for the spam folder, you can train from it using the `--mbox` switch:

```
sa-learn --spam --mbox /path/to/spam_mbox
```

Comment: So I upload the contents of my spam folder in thunder bird to e.g. /tmp/spam folder an execute above command?

Comment: @Cudos Yes, copy the Spam folder mbox file from your Thunderbird profile and then run the above command. You can find further documentation for sa-learn at http://spamassassin.apache.org/full/3.2.x/doc/sa-learn.html